# OPENCART Search by category questions

Tags: php, search, opencart2.x

I am using OPENCART 2.0, I need to figure out how to make the search function be able to search by category. Right now it only allows searching by product. The site is an ink and toner eCommerce site. A lot of customers don't know what ink they need so they search using their printer model name. The printer Model names are the categories, so I need all corresponding ink cartridges to show up when that particular printer is searched. The site is www.1stclassink.com

I have been playing around with the common.js file, and was able to make the product search , search also using product description. But I am not sure how to get to the categories. Any help would be appreciated.

I have been messing with this bit of code:

```
/* Search */
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').on('click', function() {
    url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

    var value = $('header input[name=\'search\']').val();

    if (value) {

        url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&description=true';  //search parameters

    }

    location = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am php developer But I didn't worked upon opencart's yet. But as i watched to your code, it seems to be understanding to me. I think this may work. try this out:

```
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').on('click', function() {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
        }

        location = url;
    });

    $('#header input[name=\'filter_name\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

            var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

            if (filter_name) {
                url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
            }

            location = url;
        }
    });
```

and your header file will be look like this:

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="button-search"></div>
    <?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you could search categories by name.
What you could do is get all the products that are under a certain category, for that you will need the **category's id** (for example: all products under category_id=20):

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=&category_id=20
```

What you need to do is *find a way to get the category's id from the search input*, I can't find an easy way to do it at the moment but you could:

- **1. Modify the categories model** by adding a function inside `catalog/model/catalog/category.php`:

  ```php
  public function getCategoryByName($category_name) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "category_description WHERE name LIKE '%".$category_name."%'");

      if(isset($query->row[0]['category_id'])) return $query->row[0]['category_id'];
      return false;
  }
  ```
- **2. Modify the `index()` function** inside `catalog/contoller/product/search.php` to look for a Get parameter
  you would send (example `&category=true`) and then call your function
  `getCategoryByName()` [after loading the category model] to get a
  `category_id` then integrate it with the reste of the `index()`
  function.
- **2'**. Or, **Create a controller to handle an AJAX request**, get the `category_id` and plug it through JQuery to your url:

  "index.php?route=product/search&search=&category_id=" + category_id

**N.B:** This is a simple code, I did not test it, so make sure it is ready for your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am having a bit of trouble in the search file catalog/controller/product/search.php . I am not sure how to correctly integrate the function into the code. The index() function is quite large. I load the the category model, and attempt to tap into one of the if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) statements. But it is a little confusing as to how to integrate everything.

Comment: I know it's hard to understand all that code in `search.php`, but it's quite simple if you ask yourself the right questions: "What do want to do?". I want to **1) inject the `category_id`** that I get from my model function, and **2) make sure that we don't search product name**.  So all what we need to do is set `$category_id`, and make sure `$search = '';`. yes but how? easy, we change them at the last minute :). Look for `$data['products'] = array();` in the `index()` function of `search.php`. then add:

Comment: `if (isset($this->request->get['category_search']) && isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
   $this->load->model('catalog/category');
   $category_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryByName($search);
   $search = '';
  }`

Comment: This code is simple: **1)** we test if our custom GET attribute is here `category_search` **[don't forget to add it in your url: ` url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&description=true' + '&category_search=true';`]**. **2)** we make sure the user typed something in the search. **3)** we call our method form the model. 4) we empty the search to **make sure that we don't trigger a specific product search**. Test this code and tell me what you get :) .**N.B**: I did not test that code, please make sure it handles all possible errors.

Comment: Can you give me some feed back, did it work for you?